# Why edx studio run rake cms bad?

Tags: javascript, django, coffeescript, edx

I'm trying to run edx studio like:
rake cms
But when i'm open my site, some js and coffeescripts have status code 304, that's why some content doesn't work

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the Githib page?

Answer (score -1):

You need to give us more informations - how did you install edx components.

It's better to use these instructions:
https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki#installation 
Then those in edx-platform github project as they are soon going to be deprecated (said by John Jarvis in edx-code google group).

There are two options: developer setup or public setup (for production). In developer setup you run lms with `lms[cms.dev,0.0.0.0:8000]` and cms with command `rake cms[dev,0.0.0.0:8001]`

And then you can access them on ipOfYourServer:8000 and ipOfYourServer:8001.